# App crashes when adding a button

Tags: java, android

I want to display a button in front of a canvas in a game I'm making. But now my application crashes without errors.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
        myButton.setId(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings);
        myButton.setClickable(true);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layout_82 = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Ib = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(myButton.getLayoutParams());
        Ib.setMargins(50, 100, 0, 0);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(layout_82);

        registerForContextMenu(myButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant call `myButton.getLayoutParams()` before you add `myButton` to a layout. `myButton.getLayoutParams()` will return null and crash

Comment: how would i add myButton

Answer (score 0):

you haven't added the button to your layout - Call `ViewGroup.addView(myButton);` with viewgroup being the thing you want to add your button to.

Comment: `Ib` is not a layout

Comment: I add this to the code but it still crashes.                                                                                             MainActivity.addView(myButton);

    }

    public static void addView(ImageButton myButton) {
    }

Comment: You  need to add the button to a viewgroup like a linear layout, or a relative layout or something similar.  Needs to be something that exists already on your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findViewById()` method to get any container from `R.layout.activity_main`, and add the button to this container with `addView()` method.
Container can be any subclass of `ViewGroup` (`*Layout`).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html